# How to get properties just of the prototype chain and not of the object itself?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
var Animal = function() { };
Animal.prototype.size = 'small';
Animal.prototype.height = '50';

var Mammal = function() { };
Mammal.prototype = new Animal();
Mammal.prototype.name = 'rabbit';
Mammal.prototype.nickname = 'aaa';

var Rabbit = function(nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
};
Rabbit.prototype = new Mammal();
Rabbit.prototype.name = 'bbbbbbb';

var myRabbit = new Rabbit('Cutie');
```

For this object I want to divide its properties into two groups: its own properties and properties inherited from its prototype chain. So I do this:

```
function getObj(obj){
    var ownKeys = Object.keys(obj); // it's ok, I get 'nickname'

    var protoKeys = [];
    var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); // here I can't get all of the properties
    console.log(props);
}
```

The problem is that the properties names are the same in several cases. And I can't get all properties of prototype chain (name, name, nickname, size, height) as I suppose because of that.

Is there any way to get all prototype chain properties? Or their names must be unique?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think the way you implement inheritance locks You, doesn't it sounds strange that 
`myRabbit.constructor.name` is `Animal` (once all constructor are properly unanonimized)?

Comment: @fedeghe 9, thank you for your comment. I'm new to prototype chain and of course there can be a mistake. How would you create an object like this? Could you please, write some example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fedeghe You're absolutely right - the name of each constructor must be specified!

Comment: sure ...is a bit different, I suggest to take a look at the difference (one already spotted) instead of `var A = function (){}` use `function A(){}` and that kind of declaration is really useful even if not a called as constructor....
`a(); var a= function(){}; //error` instead
`a(); function a(){} //perfectly valid`
have fun!

Comment: @fedeghe, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var props = [];
var proto = obj;

// We go through a chain of prototypes    
while(proto !== null) {
    if (proto!==null) {
        var tmp = {};
        // For each prototype collect property values
        Object.keys(proto).forEach( function(p) {
            tmp[p] = proto[p];
        });
        props.push(tmp);
        proto = proto.__proto__;
    }
}

console.log(props);
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed! Just one little question: in the result array (that console shows) there is an empty object in the end. Is it OK and maybe it is possible to get rid of it?

Comment: nice...... I would use `Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)` instead of `proto.__proto__`

Comment: is the one related to the top most Object ... add `props.pop()` ... after the while to clean it

Comment: @Ms.Smith It's okay, it's the topmost object. Remove it from the array is not necessarily because the properties can be assigned to him.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fun(){ return this; }
fun.prototype.firstname = 'yogesh';
fun.prototype.lastname = 'jagdale';

var f = new fun();

for(var proto in f.constructor.prototype){
   console.log(proto)
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped, but my chain is longer and I can't get all properties...

Answer (score 1):

Use `for..in` loop to iterate through object properties and `Object.hasOwnProperty` method to filter out all "local" object properties:

```
var myRabbit = new Rabbit('Cutie');
var inherited_props = [];
for (var i in myRabbit) {
    if (!myRabbit.hasOwnProperty(i)) inherited_props.push(i);
}

console.log(inherited_props); // ["name", "size", "height"]
```

As for *retrieving a prototype's object property which has the same name as initial object's existing own property* - see my "previous" answer: [How do I retrieve a property from a prototype's object that is inside a constructor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496047/how-do-i-retrieve-a-property-from-a-prototypes-object-that-is-inside-a-construc/37496859#37496859)

Comment: thank you for your answer. It helped me, but for me it was really important to get also the properties that have the same names as other properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list the enumerable properties inherited by an object `obj`, you can use

```
var props = [],
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
for(var prop in proto)
  props.push(prop);
```

Usually, in case `obj` is an instance of a constructor `Constr`, you can also get the [[Prototype]] like

```
var proto = Constr.prototype;
var proto = obj.constructor.prototype;
```

If you want to get non-enumerable properties too, you will have to iterate the prototypical chain manually:

```
var props = new Set(), // Use a set to avoid repetitions
    proto = obj;
while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto))
  for(var prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto))
    props.add(prop);
```

If you don't want to avoid repetitions, use an array instead of a set:

```
var props = [],
    proto = obj;
while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto))
  props.push.apply(props, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto));
```

Or with repetitions without non-enumerable:

```
var props = [],
    proto = obj;
while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto))
  props.push.apply(props, Object.keys(proto));
```

Comment: thank you very much! It helped me a lot, especially the last part "with repetitions without non-enumerable"